# XAMPP and PyMySQL not integrating correctly

Tags: python, xampp, pymysql

I am running XAMPP control panel 3.2.2 in order to have Apache and MySQL hosted, and I have correctly imported PyMySQL and cgi, which I have verified to be installed.

However, when I try and run a test script to make sure that everything is working together, it prints part of the program correctly, but not the other stuff. Images attached.

How do I fix this? I have tried Googling solutions but nothing to solve it has come up, and the python.exe location is definitely correct.

[Modules verified](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qi8j4.png)

[Program displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Lsz2.png)

[Test program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KRJ8o.png)

[XAMPP running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yuRO3.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright I fixed it, here is how I did it for anyone looking at this question:

1. Open the Apache httpd.conf configuration file from XAMPP
2. Locate the AddHandler block of code using CTRL-F
3. Where it says

   ```
   AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl .asp
   ```

   Add .py to the end of the list so it instead becomes:

   ```
   AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl .asp .py
   ```
4. Save the file with .py appended onto it
5. Restart XAMPP and then launch the file from a web browser, where it should be working